# postgresql: посчитать элементы в конкретном значении поля

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, plpgsql

В текстовом поле res таблицы main лежит такая структура:

```
которую получаю запросом: SELECT res FROM main WHERE id = 5;

{
 "abc": {
        "a": {
             "x": {"p": "val"},
             "y": {"p": "msg", "b": 33, "ms": 0},
             "z": {"p": "msg ", "b": 12, "ms": 0}
        },
        "b": ["x", "y", "z"], 
        "c": [
             [69, "text_05", "m n o"],
             [4, " text_02", "def"],
             [1, "text_01", "abc "],
             [48, " text_04 ", "jkl"],
             [5, " text_03 ", " ghi"],
             [82, "text_06  ", " pq r "]
             ]
        },
 "xyz": {
        "z": [
             [11, "aaa"],
             [33, "bbb"]
             ] 
        }
 }
```

Как построить запрос, который вернёт цифру 2, - количество: "abc" и "xyz".

На js делал так:

```
 var s = {
 "abc": {
        "a": {
             "x": {"p": "val"},
             "y": {"p": "msg", "b": 33, "ms": 0},
             "z": {"p": "msg ", "b": 12, "ms": 0}
        },
        "b": ["x", "y", "z"], 
        "c": [
             [69, "text_05", "m n o"],
             [4, " text_02", "def"],
             [1, "text_01", "abc "],
             [48, " text_04 ", "jkl"],
             [5, " text_03 ", " ghi"],
             [82, "text_06  ", " pq r "]
             ]
        },
 "xyz": {
        "z": [
             [11, "aaa"],
             [33, "bbb"]
             ] 
        }
 };

  var c = Object.keys(s).length;

  alert(c); // 2
```

на postgresql не получается.

Comment: Гвозди микроскопом лучше не забивать. Реляционные СУБД не предназначены для разбора текста внутри полей. Можно конечно преобразовать в json и воспользоваться функциями работы с json https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.4/functions-json

Comment: @Mike, вот у меня через json / jsonb и не получается, пробовал по Вашей ссылке. Спасибо.

Comment: select (select count(1) from json_object_keys(res)) cnt from ....

Comment: @Mike, круто, спасибо, готов отметить как решение .. может вчерашний мой вопрос у Вас будет возможность посмотреть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получаем ключи из объекта json и считаем их количество:

```
select (select count(1) from json_object_keys(res::json)) cnt
  from main WHERE id = 5;
```